# Problem with Octave and the area() method

Tags: matlab, octave

I'm trying to plot and fill the area under the graph curve using area(). It works when I give the method simple functions, ie:

```
WS = linspace(0,100,500);
x = 2.*(WS)
area(WS,x)
```

but, for some reason, this method doesn't work in Octave with 'more complex functions'.
This is the script

```
WS = linspace(0,100,500);
TW_LCV = q.*( ( CD_min./WS) + k.*( (n./q).^2 ).*(WS) ); %the parameters are not relevant
figure()
plot(WS,TW_LCV, 'r');
hold on
area(WS, TW_LCV, 'FaceColor','y')
grid on;
```

I've tried **the same script in Matlab**, and it works. How can I fix this in Octave? The output:
[image]

Note. I'm using Windows 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are likely having infinite / nan values in your array (as in the example above, resulting from a division-by-zero operation).

Replace those values by suitable values (e.g. either get rid of `inf` values, or replace them by a suitably high value - or in your case possibly a zero value if that is deemed to be the limit of `(x/WS)*WS for WS -> 0`.

Once you only have appopriate numerical values, the area function will work as expected.

Having said that, if matlab does something with infinite values which octave treats differently, feel free to report it to the octave team in their bug tracker, since the octave team tends to treat deviations from matlab behaviour as 'bugs'.

Comment: Thank you! Searching in the workspace, the first value in the vector TW_LCV is Inf. Removing 0 from WS solved my problem.